# How to extract a specific Request Header from request.headers call in Puppeteer Javascript

Tags: javascript, header, puppeteer

Im trying to figure out how to extract a specific header from a request.headers call.

```
referer: 'https://youtube.com',
 'hgrrhtrth': 'd9amne',
 'eegrergerg': 'AMDhrdCDAQAAdTwy0PBjxOH1a-4r649raXtr- 
 umppqwSDGBci1YR1DJyNrrU',
 'testheader': 'jasdndasnjqwnqwidwqin'
}
```

Lets say there is a header called testheader: jasdndasnjqwnqwidwqin , how would i call for this specific header.

```
page.on('request', request => {
    if (request.isInterceptResolutionHandled()) return;

    var requestHeaders = request.headers()
    console.log(requestHeaders)
});
```

Comment: As per the [puppeteer documentation](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.httprequest.headers) request. headers() are objects, so if you know JavaScript, you can access a particular request using [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: @Soheb it is saying the response are not objects, i cannot use .filter not even object.keys